# Linux User Permission Tutorial

Tags: permissions, tutorial

Hey guys, I used to have a bookmark to a series of articles that discussed and explained user permissions on posix environments. Today I was finally going to get around to reading it and I noticed it was no longer in my bookmarks. I even went through some of my backup bookmarks and did not find it there. Naturally I went through Google to search for some sort of permissions tutorial in hopes of finding it but I did not find it there either.

The website was nicely formatted and I *believe* had a unique name, irrelevant to the subject of linux and simply random. The series consisted of four parts if I remember correctly. I have searched for other tutorials in place of that one, but most of them seem to have been written in a hurry and don't really take the time to explain it thoroughly.

I was just wondering if any of you guys might have come across it or know which one I am referring to. I would really really appreciate it if someone could provide me with the link so that I can read it and bookmark it.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I believe that before I deleted it, when I had it, I had found it when I was trying to look-up how to chown a directory to the www-data group, it covered chmod, chown, and user/file permissions.

Comment: Could you provide the link? Perhaps someone else is searching for such a tutorial.

Comment: Oh, no, I didn't find it, I meant that I found it that one time I had it in my bookmarks, I will clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem-space of POSIX permissions (not bringing POSIX ACLs into it) is a fairly small problem space.

The Wikipedia articles are pretty decent:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chgrp

Here's a couple less "formal" articles, too. I flipped thru them quickly and they seem fairly sane:

- http://www.freeos.com/articles/4440/ - Describes permissions at a rudimentarly level and demonstrates chmod and chgrp.
- http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html - Describes using chmod, chgrp, with a little detour into AFS ACLs that is irrelevant to you.

Comment: Thank you! Voted up and I'm definitely going to keep these links around, but I would really love to have find the article(s) I am referring to because that site also had tutorials for other subjects. Thanks though I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Dave Eisenberg wrote a tutorial for chmod which I found very useful. It starts out by describing the meaning of different permission settings and then continues on to detail making changes.

http://catcode.com/teachmod/